# issubclass() behavior changes based on import

Tags: python, subclass

I'm trying to figure out why the behavior of `issubclass()` changes based on how a class was imported.

I have the following setup

```
proj
|_pkg
  |_ __init__.py
  |_ base.py
  |_ child.py
```

base.py has

```
class Base(object):
    pass
```

child.py has

```
from base import Base

class Child(Base):
    pass
```

Then I do the following in shell:

```
$export PYTHONPATH='/tmp/proj'
$ipython
In [1]: from pkg.base import Base as Base1

In [2]: from base import Base as Base2

In [3]: from pkg.child import Child as Child1

In [4]: from child import Child as Child2

In [5]: issubclass(Child1, Base1)
Out[5]: True # Makes Sense

In [6]: issubclass(Child1, Base2)
Out[6]: False # Confused. Why would this be False.

In [7]: issubclass(Child2, Base1)
Out[7]: False # Confused. Why would this be False.

In [8]: issubclass(Child2, Base2)
Out[8]: True
```

I'm confused by whats going on in In [6] and [7]. I would expect those to be `True` too.

Comment: You're ending up with two logically separate `Base` classes even though they're defined in the same source file because of the different way the module or submodule corresponding to that .py file gets `import`ed.

Comment: Usually you shouldn't run scripts from within a package for exactly this reason. That is, you should never run `python pkg/script.py` or `python script.py` from within the `pkg` folder (or run interactively there). It can work if you instead use `python -m pkg.script` from the top level folder above `pkg` (or from anywhere if `pkg` is in the module search path).

Comment: Thanks. After some digging around found the answer here - http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-double-import-trap

Answer (score 1):

After some digging around found the answer here - http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-double-import-trap

> This next trap exists in all current versions of Python, including
>   3.3, and can be summed up in the following general guideline: “Never add a package directory, or any directory inside a package, directly
>   to the Python path”.
>
> The reason this is problematic is that every module in that directory
>   is now potentially accessible under two different names: as a top
>   level module (since the directory is on sys.path) and as a submodule
>   of the package (if the higher level directory containing the package
>   itself is also on sys.path).
>
> As an example, Django (up to and including version 1.3) used to be
>   guilty of setting up exactly this situation for site-specific
>   applications - the application ends up being accessible as both app
>   and site.app in the module namespace, and these are actually two
>   different copies of the module.